# How to query in join models in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm fairly new with Laravel5. I'm still trying to learn it. My question is:

There are 2 tables：

TableA named TA  has some columns as below:

```
Name  Email  Tel1  Tel2  Tel3
```

TableB named TB has some columns as below:

```
Position  MTel  GTel
```

Table A one row can correspond many rows with Table B
Now I want to do  SQL query as below:

```
select * where
    (TA.Tel1=TB.MTel and TA.Tel2=TB.GTel) or 
    (TA.Tel1=TB.MTel and TA.Tel3=TB.GTel) or 
    (TA.Tel2=TB.MTel and TA.Tel3=TB.GTel) or 
    (TA.Tel2=TB.MTel and TA.Tel1=TB.GTel) or 
    (TA.Tel3=TB.MTel and TA.Tel1=TB.GTel) or 
    (TA.Tel3=TB.MTel and TA.Tel2=TB.GTel) and
    ( Name='myname')
```

And I build two model

Model1:

```
class TA extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'TA';

     public function TB()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TB','MTel');
    }
}
```

Model2

```
class TB extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'TB';

     public function TA()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TA','Tel1');
    }
}
```

and...I　don't know how to continue.

look forward your help ,thanks

Comment: Is this query something you always want to be applied when you try to load the relation or just one of the queries you want to run on your models?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all records from table TA that are related to a record in table TB, you could do the following in (if you are using Eloquent ofcourse):

```
TB::with('TA')->where('name','=',$name);
```

This will select the record from table TB with the corresponding name and all the records from table TA belonging to it.